# Where to start? : Developing rich web applications for mobile platforms (against platform specific standalone apps)

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, mobile, cross-platform

I am new to mobile app development and I dont want restrict myself to one platform.

Some days ago I read an article that stressed on the fact that soon web apps running on mobile browsers may replace dedicated apps (at least for non-game apps). I want to develop a social networking web app that any phone can run via the browser. These are the things I would like expert comments on:

- Resources/Guidelines for developing
  great UIs for rich mobile web apps
  (HTML5?, existing APIs/Frameworks I should know)
- The best ways to increase performance
  (a reusable native simple browser app
  per platform that caches, provides a
  uniform interface to the web apps,
  access to sensors, APIs, features
  like drag drop etc for that platform.
  is there already one?)
- How do I test the apps for various
  major platforms and across various
  devices (small/large screens, touch
  phones etc)
- Best ways to manage multiple device
  compatibility.. (how to best handle
  non-uniformity of functionality on
  various devices/browsers on the server side using ASP.NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar questions to answer for my company, please have a look at my article: [Testing Mobile Web – phones and platforms to focus on](http://nomtek.com/developers/testing-mobile-web-phones-and-platforms-to-focus-on/).

In short:

- Html 5 is now well supported on iPhone, Android and Blackberry 6.0 platforms.
- I strongly recommend to look at jQuery mobile project, especially at platform page and John Resigs excelent presentation there.
- For all of major platforms (iPhone, Android, Blackberry, Symbian) you have emulators with default web browsers
- mobile web usage statistics should always be your guide, look at StatCounter stats.

More on this you will find in my article as well as a collection of useful links for further reading.

Good luck :)